# What should I do to load images in cairo?

Tags: c, cairo

I am using images for graphics in cairo, I see that `cairo_image_surface_new_from_png()` does not accept a `FILE *`, so that is weird for me.

If I want to load assets for game graphics, what cairo function should I use? Is there any way to give cairo a tmpfile instead of a filename?

This filename stuff is really confusing to me because I dont give it a full file path. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The function you’re looking for is [`cairo_image_surface_create_from_png`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-image-surface-create-from-png), it takes a filename as its argument.